# How to search with 'MATCH' on OrientDB with case-INsensitive?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am using OrientDB version 2.2.30, and I want to search for all persons that related to a WHITE car.

Both vertex (person & entity) are set to case-insensitive on all string-properties.

The problem is that the word "white" is written with upper and lower cases and the MATCH returns only those that are a match to the exact form I write on the query.

```
MATCH {class:Person, as:E0}.outE(){class:Drive, as:R0}.inV(){class:Car, as:E1 , where:( (   CarColor IN ['white']   ) ) } RETURN $paths
```

This will return all the match-paths but only if the word "white" is written as the query: 'white' (WHIte or WHITE won't be retreived as a result even though this field is set to be case-INsensitive)

The funny thing is that if I take the condition of the color OUT from the 'match' query and place it in a 'regular' where-clause - it is working just fine and retrieve all upper&lower cases

```
SELECT  *
 FROM 
 ( MATCH {class:Person, as:E0}.outE(){class:Drive, as:R0}.inV(){class:Car, as:E1 } RETURN $paths )
WHERE ( (   E1.CarColor IN ['white']   ) )
```

But this solution causes the match query to run much longer...
So I need another solution to use "match" with conditions that will apply as case-INsensitive...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to use `.toLowerCase()` eg. `CarColor.toLowerCase() IN ['white']`

Comment: I thought about it, but how can I do the toLower() if the property 'CarColor' is emmbedded list? (and besides, Why do I need the toLower if the property is set to Case-insensitive???)

Comment: Please reffer to my comment above. I have the same issue on a property with an emmbedded list (of strings) and I don't think I can perform toLowerCase on a multi-value property...